# Why SQLAlchemy ignore timezone while filtering?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Hi I have an issue with filtering datetime field in SQLAlchemy. My local time is GMT -4 and I need to get all records for today (but according to UTC time)

Here is my code:

```
start_time = datetime.now()
start_time = start_time.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
result = session.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.time_field >= start_time).first()
```

In that case, I will get a record from 04:00:00 UTC which means it still uses my local time.
But when I add 1 second to `start_time`

```
start_time.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=1, microsecond=0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

Everything will work and I will receive the record from 00:00:10 UTC.
Can anyone explain to me why?
Thanks

- Python 2.7.10
- SQLALchemy 1.2.15
- PostgreSQL

Comment: `2022-07-13 00:04:00+00:00` is equal to `2022-07-13 00:00:00-04:00`, i.e., the very first moment of `2022-07-13` in your time zone. Your filter uses `>=` so that row is included. I don't see what the problem is here. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Hey @GordThompson thanks for your comment. The problem is that both results are in UTC time zone and they have a 4 hour difference.

Comment: Perhaps you are assuming that the query will return results in a particular (chronological) order and `.first()` will return the earliest date/time. That is not guaranteed unless you use `.order_by(MyModel.time_field)`